# Will it work if i put a div inside another div

Tags: css, html

Does div work inside another div? If so, how should I do the CSS? I just started doing this so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Did you try? What did you get so far? What is the problem?

Comment: That's not a suicide attempt, you can do and check...

Comment: Hi @Overcooking, `<div>` inside another `<div>` is valid.. and apparently a `<div>` inside a `<td>` is also valid (which shocks me, tbh). and, as the two previous comment suggest, post what you want and have you tried it? you had a sandbox tools such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)... before people stars downvoting your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a div inside div works. Basically that is how many of webpages are designed. Take a look at source of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page). Stacked divs...

So why you want to nest `<div>`? For example, you don't want your page to be over whole width of the screen, but you want it centered and to have some blank space on left and right. You would do something like

```
<div class="outside" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
    Some content...
</div>
```

But then you want to style the content inside the `outside` div. Again, you need div... **Consider divs as LEGO blocks:** you make a house out of LEGO block, but you furnish the interior of the house with LEGO blocks as well. The same is here, just substitute LEGO blocks with `<div>`. At the end you might get something like this:

```
<div class="outside" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:100%; margin-top: 20px;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
           <img src="google_logo.jpg" />
        </a>
        <p>Click on image and see what happens...</p>
        <div ...>
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Might be a poor example but just to give you an idea...

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div):

> The **HTML `<div>` element**:
>   [**Content categories**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories): [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), palpable content.
>   **Permitted content**: [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content).

It means you can put any of elements with current content category into an element that permits this content category's element inside.

For example:

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Main div
  <div>Child div</div>
</div>
```

You can do the same with some other elements, simply check [MDM HTML element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) before (or [HTML 5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html)). Also you could try [HTML 5 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/).